# How to dynamically import images in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i am using react native with expo and i need to import all images in a folder and use them by name on each loop
i used this component called FlatGrid from [react-native-super-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-super-grid)  to create a CSS grid with images
from a dictionary like this

```
[
    { name: "AppleMusic.png"},
    { name: "discord.png" },
]
```

```
<FlatGrid
          itemDimension={150}
          data={items}
          spacing={10}
          windowSize={300}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Image
                source={require(`../ui/icons/${item.name}.png`)}
              />
              <Text>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
```

but i did not work with `` source={require(`../ui/icons/${item.name}.png`)} ``  and i tried
everything  i can think of like importing the images in a seprate file and exporting them like this

```
 const images = {
  applemusic: require("../ui/icons/AppleMusic.png"),
  discord: require("../ui/icons/discord.png")
}
export default images;
```

just to help you! it did work when I imported a single image like this `import AppleMusic from "../ui/icons/AppleMusic.png";` and used it like this `source={require(AppleMusic)}` but even if i did this to all the images **(25image to be exact)** i still can't solve the problem of iterating through the imported images

Comment: Have you tried to remove the .PNG after ${item.name} ?

Comment: Please print as simple text or console log, then you can find the extension printing two times.  ...AppleMusis.png.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Image` folder create a index.js file and import all images like this

```
export const image1 = require('./image1.jpg')
export const image2 = require('./image2.jpg')
export const image3 = require('./image3.jpg')
export const image4 = require('./image4.jpg')
```

then inside your Class you can import images and use those images to create image array

```
import {image1,image2,image3,image4} from './images'

const items=[
        { name: image1},
        { name: image2 },
        { name: image3 },
        { name: image4 },
   ]
```

then you can use it like this

```
<FlatGrid
      itemDimension={150}
      data={items}
      spacing={10}
      windowSize={300}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Image
            source={item.name}
          />
          <Text>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Comment: ty so much i did try it and it did work i dont know where the problem was with my code but after trying yours it did work thank you sooo much again

Comment: @FaouziElbakri glad to hear it worked. if you accept this as Answer it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
const images = {
  applemusic: require("../ui/icons/AppleMusic.png"),
  discord: require("../ui/icons/discord.png")
}
export default images;
```

Should works!
I have tried some similar code.It works as the pic show.

```
const images = {
    test: require("../assets/test.png"),
    splash: require("../assets/splash.png"),
    icon: require("../assets/icon.png")
}

export default images
```

```
function Feed() {
    const list = ["icon", "test", "splash"];
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Feed!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    width: 200,
                    height: 50,
                    backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
                onPress={
                    () => {
                        DeviceEventEmitter.emit("ADD_COUNT")
                    }
                }
            >
                <Text>add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {
                list.map((name) => {
                    return (
                        <Image
                            source={Images[name]}
                            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]